# How do I unit test the "exists" validation rule?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I've just gotten started with unit testing (I'm reading Laravel Testing Decoded by Jeffrey Way). I'm not sure how to test the ["exists" validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists) in isolation since it queries the database. I think maybe I need to mock the database query somehow? If so, I'm not sure how to do that.

To be clear, I want to test that business rules are being enforced, not to test that the validator is working correctly. Also, I'm doing validation in the model with Ardent so it's the model that is being testing.

As an example, the "required" rule is straightforward to test. You fill every field with valid data, except for the one you are testing which is left null. Then you assert that validation failed. (The book has examples of this) But testing "exists" or "unique" needs to touch the database.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow; try [programmers.se]

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Why?

Comment: It doesn't deal with a specific programming question. See the FAQ.

Comment: It's specific to how Laravel's validation library works.

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? This question belongs on [Programmers.se]

Comment: I don't understand why you can't be more specific. Why is a question about implementing a unit test for a specific validation library off-topic?

Comment: I wouldn't mind the question on Programmers @FreshPrinceOfSO, but since it's focused on Laravel's validation library, it's more suitable for Stack Overflow than us (ProgSE mod here).

Comment: Well, I don't see this questions off topic at all. Yes, it's technical and yes, is framework related, but I don't see how will we search all of stackexchange resources (probably making questions in every one of them) to get an answer. By experience, [Database Administator](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) has very delayed views compared to the main site.

Comment: Going to the question per se, i'll recommend injecting a mock into the Validator class `\Validator::getFacadeRoot()->setPresenceVerifier($validatorMock);`. In that mock you can expect the method `getCount` be called. Give it a try. This is not unit, you're walking in integration tests territory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer:

Don't.

The test you are trying to create is something that's already tested by Laravel's core test suite.

### Longer Answer:

If you want to test that your specific rule works with your data set, then you want to make a unit test which interacts with your data!

The base `TestCase` which comes with Laravel bootstraps the app enough so that you can do this.

Perhaps [unit test with a seeded sqllite memory database](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models/) rather than with your real database.

Otherwise **you can safely assume that the [validation library is already fully tested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php#L564) and will function** - No need to re-test it. There's already tests to make sure that "exists" works as it should. The only factor left is whether your data supports the test.

### Finally:

When testing, be mindful of how useful your unit test is. You don't necessarily need 100% code coverage. You especially don't necessarily need to test what is already tested by the framework coverage. If you're curious to find out what makes a good unit test (and the difference between unit vs integration testing), check out [this excellent post about writing good tests](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: My intent is more to test that business rules are being enforced rather than test that the validator is working correctly. Sorry if that wasn't clear.